# Delete Rows in Qgis using Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes, delete, calculate-values

I tried to delete all rows where Field  "Width"  has value 2?

Comment: You tried and then what happened?

Comment: i tried the same what @Erik Lohman suggested and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, whether you directly can delete rows via the calculator (doubt so strongly), but you can use `select by expression`, type `"width" = 2` and then delete the marked rows manually.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to follow these steps to delete the rows with the value of interest, in your case 2.

1. You will need to make the layer editable

[image]

2. Open the attribute table and select the features of interest
3. Then click the delete button.

[image]

Not sure if you could use the field directly to delete.